# Ngx-Captcha issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngxs

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-captcha/v/11.0.0.
<ngx-recaptcha2 #captchaElem [siteKey]="'6Leh1ZIjAAAAAG8g0BuncTRT-VMjh3Y7HblZ9XSZ'"
(success)="handleSuccess($event)" [useGlobalDomain]="false" [size]="size" [hl]="lang" [theme]="theme"
[type]="'image'" (load)="handleLoad()" formControlName="recaptcha">

some time when i click on i am not a robot it shows image varification but some times it wont ask for validation?

why this happens,I always want to show image recaptcha after clicking on i am not robot.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that the Google captcha images will only appear if Google determined the need to verify that they are not a robot. So sometimes the image will not appear.

Comment: is there any way we can show the image everytime?